# Declare a class or struct inside a method

Tags: c#, .net

In C#, is it possible to declare a class or struct inside a method, as in C++?

e.g. C++:

```
void Method()
{
   class NewClass
   {
   } newClassObject;
}
```

I have tried, but it's not allowing me to do so.

Comment: You should be allowed to do so in a **class**, but not inside a **method**. What exactly have you tried?

Comment: Your subject says "inside method", but in your post you say "inside class". Please edit one or the other so your goal is clear.

Comment: the title asks a different question to the question body. The difference is important. Please clarify whether you mean "inside a Method" (title) vs "inside a class" (body)

Answer (score 30):

You can create an anonymous type like so:

```
var x = new { x = 10, y = 20 };
```

but other than that: no.

Comment: This an object, not a class.

Comment: Yes and no. x is a variable, but the (anonymous) type returned by x.GetClass() is a class.

Comment: That's true. I assumed that the question is about defining a classes.

Comment: @WojtekT - A class gets generated by the compiler for the code above.

Answer (score 14):

Yes, it is possible to declare a `class` inside a `class` and these are called `inner classes`

```
public class Foo
{
    public class Bar
    { 

    }
 }
```

and this how you can create an instance

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
Foo.Bar bar = new Foo.Bar();
```

And within a method you can create an object of `anonymous` type

```
void Fn()
{
 var anonymous= new { Name="name" , ID=2 };
 Console.WriteLine(anonymous.Name+"  "+anonymous.ID);
}
```

Comment: Or the class inside the class (per the original question) may be called a nested class.

Comment: The OP is asking for defining a class inside of a method. You are answering the wrong question.

Comment: @kaalus, Sleiman correctly answered the *original* (i.e, unedited) question.  Consulting edit history for the question shows that the Title and Body of the initial submission asked contradictory questions. Sleiman clearly answered both questions.  After others requested clarification, the question in the *body* was edited to match the question in the title.  I hope you didn't downvote Sleiman.

Answer (score 10):

You can declare them inside a **class** as your question states, but not inside a **method** as your question title states. Something like:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public class MyClassAgain
    {
    }

    public struct MyStruct
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In C#, there are at this moment in time no local classes within a method, but there are workarounds:

1. Use a precompiler to move the class descriptions outside of your methods (Roslyn would be helpful here)
2. If you already have an interface, you could use the NuGet package ImpromptuInterface to create a local class within your method
3. use local methods to emulate a class:

   ```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            dynamic newImpl()
            {
                int f1 = 5;
                return new { 
                    M1 = (Func<int, int, int>)((c, d) => c + d + f1), 
                    setF1 = (Func<int,int>)( p => { var old = f1; f1 = p; return old; 
                           }) };
            }
            var i1Impl = newImpl();
            var i2Impl = newImpl();
            int res;
            res = i1Impl.M1(5, 6);
            Console.WriteLine(res);

            i1Impl.setF1(10);

            res = i1Impl.M1(5, 6);
            Console.WriteLine(res);

            res = i2Impl.M1(2, 3);
            Console.WriteLine(res);

            res = i1Impl.M1(1, 2);
            Console.WriteLine(res);
        }
    }
   ```

The above prints: 16,21,10,13 .

Answer (score 0):

Today You can use tuple fields names
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples#tuple-field-names

like

```
void GetData() {
List <(string h,int hideClm, double cw, HtColumns t)> k1 = new List<(string h, int hideClm, double cw, HtColumns t)>();
        k1.Add((h: "",0,cw:50, t: new HtColumns() { type = "text" }));
        k1.Add((h: "Record time",0, cw: 190, t: new HtColumns() { type = "text" }));
        k1.Add((h: "Partner",0, cw: 290, t: new HtColumns() { type = "text" }));
}
```

Comment: That does not declare a type in that method, so while you can do it, it doesn't seem like a proper answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

The funny thing is, the runtime does have what is necessary to support local types: the `System.Type` class contains a `DeclaringMethod` member, which will be set when the type is an anonymous type declared within a method. But the language does not support declaring anything other than tuples and anonymous types within methods.

Which is a pity, because method-local types are extremely useful in tests, in order to:

1. Keep each type close to where it is used
2. Avoid polluting the namespace of the test class
3. Prevent one test method from accidentally using types meant to be used by another test method.

To achieve two out of the three goals listed above, I do the following:

1. I declare my test class as `partial`.
2. I put each test method in a separate part of the test class. (All parts in the same file.)
3. The types that would have been declared within test methods if the language allowed it, can then be declared between the parts of the test class, in essence right before each method that they belong to.